# Як перекласти українською "лично в руки"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Будь ласка, допоможіть перекласти українською мовою вислів "лично в руки".

Наприклад, я хочу відправити лист чи посилку поштою та бажаю, щоб вона була доставлена поштою саме "лично в руки" адресату.

Як може виглядати українська версія перекладу, та чи існує офіційний український переклад, який вживається, наприклад, Укрпоштою чи взагалі в українській мові? Дякую за допомогу!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Особисто в руки**

У "Нової пошти" є така [послуга](https://novaposhta.ua/news/rubric/3/id/1805) "Доставка *особисто в руки*".

Укрпошта:

> Найвагомішою можна назвати гарантію доставки рекомендованого листа
>   *особисто в руки* отримувача, за його вибором – у відділенні поштового
>   зв’язку або вдома, що сприятиме економії його часу.

P.S. Хоча мене особисто не влаштовує слово "доставка".

Comment: [Обирайте](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=доставка&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on) що схочете. Особисто мені найбільше подобається _достава_.

Comment: Доправа, доправити))

Comment: Ця відповідь є неповною. Пошук у словниках відсутній. Який вираз є вживанішим серед інтернетів — також. Окрім НП є й інші перевізники (зокрема, згадана в запитанні Укрпошта)

Answer (score 8):

*"Вручити особисто"*, як це й зазначає законодавець у [Правилах надання послуг поштового зв'язку](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/270-2009-%D0%BF):

> *Рекомендовані поштові картки, листи та бандеролі з позначкою **"Вручити особисто"**, […] приймаються для пересилання лише з рекомендованим повідомленням про їх вручення.*

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Я відредагував кілька ваших відповідей; будь ласка, перегляньте зміни і оформлення. Також, декілька інших відповідей містять лише суб'єктивні думки автора. Такі відповіді не заохочуються, бо вони лише запрошують до спростувань (що зробити легко, бо доказів не наведено). Думаю, варто ті відповіді відредагувати, додати пояснення (обов'язково), посилання на поважні джерела (дуже бажано), ну і можна ще поправити оформлення (бажано, але не обов'язково). Можна ще озирнутися навколо і поглянути, як інші користувачі робили свої відповіді.

Comment: Дякую за настанову, неодмінно вчитимуся у більш досвідчених користувачів.